# @Transactional makes getClass return com.sun.proxy.$Proxy on class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Recently I had to drop Spring Boot (2.0.0) from application and use pure spring in it (spring boot is set at depedency manager so the versions are the same).

```
public interface I {
  void doSth();
}

@Service
public class A implements I {
  @Transactional
  public void doSth(){
  }
}

public class XYZ {
 @Autowired
 public void registerI(I[] array){
  array[0].getClass() //returns com.sun.proxy.$Proxy73 
 }
}
```

Because of that `array[0].getClass()` started to return `com.sun.proxy.$Proxy73` instead of `com.package.path.A`. Other classes that implements `I` and don't have `@Transactional` act like before.

1. Why is this happening? I assume it's because `@Transactional` uses AOP but still don't understand why (edit: why it makes class Proxy, not why it uses it).
2. Why it doesn't act like that when I use Spring Boot? Does spring boot has some depedency thats override it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right spring use AOP for @Transactional method (how do you want to decorate method without AOP ?).

> The most important concepts to grasp with regard to the Spring Framework’s declarative transaction support are that this support is enabled via AOP proxies, and that the transactional advice is driven by metadata (currently XML- or annotation-based). The combination of AOP with transactional metadata yields an AOP proxy that uses a TransactionInterceptor in conjunction with an appropriate PlatformTransactionManager implementation to drive transactions around method invocations.

Spring Boot 2.0 uses CGLIB proxying by default, including for the AOP support. But spring framework will use jdk proxy instead.

See [spring boot migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#default-proxying-strategy)

> Spring Boot now uses CGLIB proxying by default, including for the AOP support. If you need proxy-based proxy, you’ll need to set the spring.aop.proxy-target-class to false.

And [spring framework aop documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-introduction-proxies)

> Spring AOP defaults to using standard JDK dynamic proxies for AOP proxies. This enables any interface (or set of interfaces) to be proxied.